# Is XMLHttpRequest always available?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

To use `XMLHttpRequest` in order to retrieve data from the server from javascript code, do I need to do conditional checks on the type of browser the code is running?
Is the following **standard** boilerplate code when using `XMLHttpRequest`?

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
  }  
else  
  {// code for IE6, IE5  
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
  }
```

Or this is no longer required?
I assume that using some other library just saves from these checks?

Comment: On modern browsers, yes. jQuery 2.0 assumes that it is. jQuery 1.9, however, doesn't.

Comment: @Blender:So code like this:http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp is standard boilerplate code when using an `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: @Blender:The newer version makes more compatibility checks than the older?I assume this is due to bad assumption i.e. bug in the older version?

Comment: 2.0 doesn't check for IE's `ActiveXObject` version.

Comment: jQuery 2.0 does not support IE 6, 7 and 8, so it does not need to check.

Comment: @Cratylus please don't use w3schools as a reference. They're full of errors.

Comment: @JanDvorak:Well their links come up first in the search result when we google

Comment: @Cratylus Unfortunately Google orders the links by popularity, not by quality.

Comment: @Cratylus: that unfortunately does not make them correct. See also http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @Cratylus This doesn't show much about their quality. It fact, w3schools is about the worst resource you can get on the internet. Use the [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) instead

Answer (score 0):

IE 5 and 6 don't support the xmlhttprequest object and you need to create an active x object so if you expect users to have IE 6 or 5 then you should check. As far as I know all other browsers have an XMLHttpRequest.

If you're relying on [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers in your xmlHttpRequests then you have to use [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE versions smaller than 10 and larger than 7 (don't think IE 7 has support for CORS at all XMLHttpRequest, XDomainRequest or otherwise).

Comment: Most likely it's because your answer seems unrelated to the question, or way off. Not sure why you're mentioning CORS. Also, IE5 and IE6 are dead. I believe that's what the asker meant when saying "no longer".

Comment: CORS is a standard that browsers support in their XHR request objects but NOT in IE 8 and 9. If you don't use CORS in your XHR that doesn't mean someone else isn't planning to do so. Assuming that the browser has a XMLHttpRequest object and implements your CORS request successfully will be wrong. Before the OP updated the question he mentioned checking browser type; feature type checking is preferred to checking for browser so it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Also, what is (was) the "Example of feature detection" paragraph doing there? It looks like a failed copy-paste. I don't think the following paragraph is an example of feature-detection.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thank you for your reply. Quoted the OP; I thought he was hinting at a browser detection script to create the XHR request, feature detection is preferred but then forgot to provied an example. Removed that part.